# Haproxy Load Balancer, EC2, writing my own availability script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ping, haproxy

I've been looking at high availability solutions such as heartbeat, and keepalived to failover when an haproxy load balancer goes down. I realised that although we would like high availability it's not really a requirement at this point in time to do it to the extent of the expenditure on having 2 load balancer instances running at any one time so that we get instant failover (particularly as one lb is going to be redundant in our setup).

My alternate solution is to fire up a new load balancer EC2 instance from an AMI if the current load balancer has stopped working and associate it to the elastic ip that our domain name points to. This should ensure that downtime is limited to the time it takes to fire up the new instance and associate the elastic ip, which given our current circumstance seems like a reasonably cost effective solution to high availability, particularly as we can easily do it multi-av zone. I am looking to do this using the following steps:

1. Prepare an AMI of the load balancer
2. Fire up a single ec2 instance acting as the load balancer and assign the Elastic IP to it
3. Have a micro server ping the current load balancer at regular intervals (we always have an extra micro server running anyway)
4. If the ping times out, fire up a new EC2 instance using the load balancer AMI
5. Associate the elastic ip to the new instance
6. Shut down the old load balancer instance
7. Repeat step 3 onwards with the new instance

I know how to run the commands in my script to start up and shut down EC2 instances, associate the elastic IP address to an instance, and ping the server.

My question is what would be a suitable ping here? Would a standard ping suffice at regular intervals, and what would be a good interval? Or is this a rather simplistic approach and there is a smarter health check that I should be doing?

*Also if anyone foresees any problems with this approach please feel free to comment*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand exactly where you're coming from, my company is in the same position. We care about having a highly available fault tolerant system however the overhead cost simply isn't viable for the traffic we get.

1. One problem I have with your solution is that you're assuming the micro instance and load balancer wont both die at the same time. With my experience with amazon I can tell you it's defiantly possible that this could happen, however unlikely, its possible that whatever causes your load balancer to die also takes down the micro instance.
2. Another potential problem is you also assume that you will always be able to start another replacement instance during downtime. This is simply not the case, take for example an outage amazon had in their us-east-1 region a few days ago. A power outage caused one of their zones to loose power. When they restored power and began to recover the instances their API's were not working properly because of the sheer load. During this time it took almost 1 hour before they were available. If an outage like this knocks out your load balancer and you're unable to start another you'll be down.

That being said. I find the ELB's provided by amazon are a better solution for me. I'm not sure what the reasoning is behind using HAProxy but I recommend investigating the ELB's as they will allow you to do things such as auto-scaling etc.

For each ELB you create amazon creates one load balancer in each zone that has an instance registered. These are still vulnerable to certain problems during severe outages at amazon like the one described above. For example during this downtime I could not add new instances to the load balancers but my current instances ( the ones not affected by the power outage ) were still serving requests.

UPDATE 2013-09-30

Recently we've changed our infrastructure to use a combination of ELB and HAProxy. I find that ELB gives the best availability but the fact that it uses DNS load balancing doesn't work well for my application. So our setup is ELB in front of a 2 node HAProxy cluster. Using this tool [HAProxyCloud](https://github.com/SBRDevelopment/HAProxyCloud) I created for AWS I can easily add auto scaling groups to the HAProxy servers.

Comment: Actually I've already got ELB running and done lots of load tests on it and now I'm working on an haproxy set up. It's all about performance, ELB can't seem to handle bursts as well as I'd like and the CNAME resolution increases the latency. That said ELB takes off all the administration overhead in fault tolerance and autoscaling, I still have to sort out all the autoscaling scripts for haproxy.

Comment: If the ELB can't handle the burst you need then ask AWS support to increase the default size of your ELB instance. They will move your ELB to an instance that can handle your load. This is a common problem while testing, I've never had this happen under a real user scenario. The CNAME resolution should be very minimal. Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason for HAProxy based LB's vs Amazon ELB's is that HAProxy is cloud agnostic. If you use ELB's you've got a lot of work to do if you want to move your infrastucture to another cloud provider... whereas if you create your own LB's based on HAProxy, you're free to divert your entire system to any cloud you choose... or even better just part of it, the point is you're not locked in to a single provider.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but the solution you suggest is overcomplicated, there's a much simpler method that does exactly what you're trying to accomplish...

Just put your HAProxy machine, with your custom AMI in an auto-scaling group with a minimum AND maximum of 1 instance.  That way when your instance goes down the ASG will bring it right back up, EIP and all.  No external monitoring necessary, same if not faster response to downed instances.

Comment: @DGM  you can use the instance user-data to call the ec2 cli on boot and reattach it, or cook the AMI with a similar call in /etc/rc.local